# cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit due to indexing)

Tags: pointers, compiler-errors, rust

I'm currently learning Rust and writing simple game. But there is an error. There is a vector of Character(s) (enum) and when trying to return value (value at some index of vector) the compiler shows the error below

```
rustc main.rs
field.rs:29:9: 29:39 error: cannot move out of dereference
                (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
field.rs:29         self.clone().field[index - 1u] as int
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

main.rs:

```
mod field;

fn main() {
    let mut field = field::Field::new(3u);
    field.change_cell(1, field::Character::X);
    println!("{}", field.get_cell(1));
}
```

field.rs:

```
pub enum Character {
    NONE, X, O,
}

pub struct Field {
    field: Vec<Character>,
    size: uint,
    cells: uint,
}

impl Field {
    pub fn new(new_size: uint) -> Field {
        Field {
            field: Vec::with_capacity(new_size*new_size),
            size: new_size,
            cells: new_size*new_size,
        }
    }

    pub fn change_cell(&mut self, cell_number: uint, new_value: Character) -> bool {
        ...
    }

    pub fn get_cell(&self, index: uint) -> int {
        self.field[index - 1u] as int
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, you should try to create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This helps us answer your question faster and might help you solve the problem yourself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a MCVE for your problem:

```
enum Character {
    NONE, X, O,
}

fn main() {
    let field = vec![Character::X, Character::O];
    let c = field[0];
}
```

Compiling this [on the Playpen](http://is.gd/JrM4Y3) has these errors:

```
error: cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
     let c = field[0];
             ^~~~~~~~
note: attempting to move value to here
     let c = field[0];
         ^
to prevent the move, use `ref c` or `ref mut c` to capture value by reference
     let c = field[0];
         ^
```

The problem is that when you use indexing, you are invoking the [Index trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) which returns a reference into the vector. Additionally, there is syntax sugar that *implicitly dereferences* that value. This is a good thing, as people usually don't expect a reference as the result.

When you assign the value to another variable, you run into trouble. In Rust, you can't copy things willy-nilly, you have to mark items as `Copy`able. This tells Rust that it is safe to make a bit-for-bit copy of that item:

```
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
enum Character {
    NONE, X, O,
}
```

This allows the MCVE to compile.

What if your item *isn't* `Copy`able? Then it's only safe to have references to your value:

```
let c = &field[0];
```